# perl Dancer problems while running CGI with dispatch.cgi

Tags: apache, perl, sqlite, cgi, dancer

I'm  trying  to  get  my  project running on Dancer (perl 5.16.3 and centos 5.10), and so far it was pleasant experience - until I tried to deploy it on server.

I've  decided to do the simplest thing and run it as CGI app with help
of default dispatch.cgi script from Dancer distribution.

I  used  default  apache  settings from [Dancer::Deployment](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Deployment.pod#Running-as-a-cgi-script-or-fast-cgi-under-Apache) manual, but
something  went  wrong.  After  a  day  of  struggle with half-working
project  I  deduced the following strange thing: while running through
dispatch.cgi,  my project is able to read from sqlite database, but it
cannot  write  into  database, so Dancer::Session::DBI was not working
properly and hence the problems.

If I run the project with stand-alone **app.pl** or with

```
plackup -E production -p 80 bin/app.pl
```

it  works  fine  and able to insert data into DB. I've tried to change
permissions to 0666 on sqlite db file, but it didn't help.

So why there's a problem with sqlite while running as CGI, and how to fix this?

Comment: When run in `cgi` the script is using your web-server's user and not the owner of the script and that user will need to have read/write access to the sqlite db file. Allow apache read/write permissions to the SQLite file and you should be all set.

Comment: Well, yeah. As I said I even made dbase file universally writeable, with no success. Also I changed owner to apache's user - the same.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was permissions problem, but not for the dbase file - for directory contained that file!
Apparently, sqlite creates some temp files while updating bases.
Beware.